# SQL SERVER - reading excel files content and transfer to sql database using xp_cmdshell

Tags: sql-server, excel, xp-cmdshell

I was shocked when I learned that importing the excel data to sql database using OPENROWSET has downsides as it truncates the cells' values of it to 255-length-characters before it passes to the database. I'm now thinking of using xp_cmdshell to read the excel file's data and transfer it to database. however I'm clueless on how I could do that. could somebody help me to achieve that?

Comment: You might want to look into `BCP`, this link would help - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/use-a-format-file-to-bulk-import-data-sql-server

Comment: Lots of good content in this discussion: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/18b7ad7d-48dc-4f3b-bdab-216f461b684a/ssis-wizard-cannot-import-text-columns-longer-then-255-using-excel-source?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: Hi @Abhishek - I tried to search my query on the link you provided but failed to find that suites to my need. I also viewed JohnLBevan's provided link and none of it gives the answer to my problem.

Comment: @ajgo - if you are looking for importing data from file to `sql server` table(s) then one option is `BCP`. `xp_cmdshell` will only spawn a windows command shell and pass in a string for execution in your case which can be a `BCP` command.

Comment: @Abhishek - can I use BCP on importing the data from .xlsx file to sql server table?

Comment: @ajgo - definitely you can, for more details see answer section

Answer (score 0):

Yes `BCP` could be used to import data from excel(.xlsx) files into `Sql Server` tables. Only thing to remember here is from [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-data-from-excel-to-sql) -

> Prerequisite - Save Excel data as text To use the rest of the methods
>   described on this page - the BULK INSERT statement, the BCP tool, or
>   Azure Data Factory - first you have to export your Excel data to a
>   text file.
>
> In Excel, select File | Save As and then select Text (Tab delimited)
>   (*.txt) or CSV (Comma delimited) (*.csv) as the destination file type.

A sample `BCP` command to import data from a excel file (converted to tab delimited) into `Sql Server table` -

```
bcp.exe "MyDB_Copy.dbo.Product" in "C:\Users\abhishek\Documents\BCPSample.txt" -c -t"\t" -r"\n" -S ABHISHEK-HP -T -h TABLOCK
```

Read more about BCP and import [here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/working-with-the-bcp-command-line-utility/).

Comment: I tried using this approach but it always imports 0 rows. I use this synyax: bcp "DbName.dbo.TableName" in "C:\MyFolder\MyExcelFile.xlsx" -S MyServer\loginname -T..